# The Little Schemer 4th Edition: rember function discussion

Tags: scheme, the-little-schemer

On page 41 after simplification of the `rember` function, there is a question-respond that I don't understand very well.

```
Q: So why don't we simplify right away?
R: Because then a function's structure does not coincide with its argument's structure.
```

I have tried to figure it out for a couple of days, but I don't understand what exactly means that question-respond.

Could anyone explain me what Friedman want to show with that question-respond?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Programmers Stackexchange would be more appropriate place for this discussion.

Comment: Thanks for comment @plaes I put the question here because I saw that StackOverflow already have a _the-little-schemer_ tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Up until this point in the chapter, recursions on lists had been written using a `cond` with two conditions, where the second condition was in turn another `cond`. That's what the author meant with "the argument structure" (a list) not coinciding with "the function structure" (a two-condition `cond`) - because now the function is structured as a single `cond` with three conditions, simpler and easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks @Óscar with your answer and this [post](http://bit.ly/Nse9lv) I understood what Friedman meant